# How to tab through components and stay inside same FocusScope?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf window with multiple panels. Each panel is a focus scope and contains a few textboxes. If the user tabs through the textboxes in one panel, the Keyboard focus should never jump out of this panel. Once the last textfield in the focos scope loses its focus, the Keyboard focus should continue with the first field of the same focus scope.

Can this be accomplished with native c# behaviour?

Comment: This was probably a stupid question. Already found out, that you can put this inside the XAML Control definition:   

    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the following two properties for that behavior:

```
FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
```